# What is the justsification for this restriction on UG?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In my textbook, there is a restriction on universal generalization:
*UG must not be used within the scope of an indented sequence(i.e. conditional proof or indirect proof) if the instantial variable y is free in the first line of that sequence.*

Then the book gives a example using conditional proof:

1.∀x(Rx)→∀x(Sx)$\quad Premise$

$\quad$2.Rx  $\quad ACP$

$\quad$3.∀x(Rx)  $\quad 2.UG(Invalid)$

$\quad$4.∀x(Sx)  $\quad 1,3 \; MP$

$\quad$5.Sx  $\quad 4.UI$

6.Rx→Sx  $\quad 2-5\;  CP$

7.∀x(Rx→Sx)  $\quad 6\; UG$

This proof is invalid. However, I don't know what is the logic of this restriction. The UG used in line 3 looks perfectly fine to me. Since the "Rx" in the second line, as my book claims, is a statement function, which does not have truth value unless the variable is replaced by a constant, then what does the assertion of "Rx" in line 2 mean? Probably the assertion of "Rx" means that this statement function is **always** true. But if I take this meaning, then it seems that line 3 just reexpresses the sense of line 2, and then the UG used here  just looks valid. And I find it interesting that this restriction applies only to conditional proof and indirect proof, but why only them? I'm just confused by it.

Comment: The details of these systems tend to vary from book to book, but it seems that the $x$ in line 2 really means some *fixed* object $x$. You'd need to read the details of how these "indented" proofs are used in the book's system. In any case, you can tell that the deduction is invalid overall. For example, say $Rx$ is "$x$ is even," and $Sx$ is "$x$ is odd." Then for the set $\mathbf{Z}$, the implication "if every number is even, then every number is odd" is vacuously true, yet "for any number, if it is even, then it is odd" is obviously false. So you should be convinced there's a problem.

Comment: I edited the title. "What is the logic of X" can be misread as "what 'logic' is generated by X". For example, some rules may generate the usual first-order logic, while other rules generate other logics.

Comment: In the kind of proof system here, when you assume "$Rx$" as an assumption, you are assuming that it holds for *some* $x$. That is why the rule needs to be limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that :

> $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x(\varphi)$

is **not** *valid* in first-order logic.

Basically, steps 2-3 in the (fallacious) proof of the question amounts to this; assume $\varphi$ [i.e. $Rx$] and infer $\forall x(\varphi)$ [i.e. $\forall x (Rx)$].

In order to show that the formula $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x \varphi$ is not in general correct, consider the following example :

> $\varphi$ is $x > 0$

and take as the domain of the interpretation the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers.

Thus, the formula :

> $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x(\varphi)$

means :

> $x > 0 \rightarrow \forall x(x > 0)$

which is not *true* in $\mathbb N$.

We have to recall the basic semantic definitions; see Herbert Enderton, A Mathematical Introduction to Logic (2nd - 2001), page 83 :

> we will define what it means for [a structure] $\mathfrak A$ to satisfy $\varphi$ with $s$ [where the *assignement* function $s : Var \to |\mathfrak A|$ is a function from the set $Var$ of all variables into the *universe* $|\mathfrak A|$ of $\mathfrak A$] :
>
> > $$\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi [s]$$
>
> $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi [s]$ if and only if the translation of $\varphi$ determined by $\mathfrak A$, where the variable $x$ is translated as $s(x)$ wherever it occurs free, is true.

In our example, if we consider $s$ such that $s(x)=1$, we have that :

> $(x > 0)[s]$ is $1>0$, which is *true* in $\mathbb N$, while obviously $\forall x (x > 0)[s]$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$ [because **not** $0>0$].

Thus :

> **not**  $\mathbb N \vDash ((x > 0) \rightarrow \forall x(x > 0))[s]$

i.e. the above assignment $s$ does not satisfy our formula in $\mathbb N$.

Thus, according to the semantic "convention" regarding formulae with free variables, having found an assignment $s$ such that the formula is not satisfied by $s$ in $\mathbb N$, we say that the formula is **not** *true* in $\mathbb N$. [*Note.* Intuitively, a formula $\alpha(x)$ with free variable $x$ is said to be true in $\mathfrak A$ if every sentence obtained from it by replacing $x$ by an arbitrary element $s(x) \in |\mathfrak A|$ is true.]

*Conclusion*

Having found an interpretation in which the formula :

> $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x(\varphi)$

is not *true*, we conclude that it is **not** *valid*.

---

*This is the reason for the restriction regarding the application of $UG$ ...*

---

*Added*

In David's answer you can find a different explanation : the key-point is the *invalidity* of :

> $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x(\varphi)$.

As you probably know, there are different *proof systems* for first-order logic : *Natural Deduction*, *Hilbert-style*, ...

But all must be *sound*, i.e. they must not be able to prove *invalid* formulae.

In order to prevent this, there are some restrictions needed.

Regarding our example, we can roughly say that the problem is connected with the interplay between *Generalization* (your $UG$) and *Conditional Proof* (or *Deduction Theorem*).

Thus, different systems adopt different restrictions :

- we can have (see my answer) an unrestricted *Conditional Proof* and put restrictions on *Generalization*,

or (see David's answer) :

- we "prefer" an unrestricted *Generalization*, in which case we need restrictions on the *Deduction Th*.

Comment: Do you include $0$ in the natural numbers? I ask because $x > 0 \rightarrow \forall x(x > 0)$ is true in $\mathbb N := \{ 1,2,3... \} $ .

Comment: @john - yes I do; but is a matter of "taste"... See the post [How is $\mathbb N$ actually defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417042/how-is-mathbb-n-actually-defined)

Comment: If $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x(\varphi)$ is invalid, why is it listed as a proof method for non-indented proofs. Why is it only invalid in the indented part? Specifically the rule "$Fy$ we can infer $ \forall x (Fx )$" should never be allowed.
Also regarding restrictions on universal, you say there are two approaches;
we can have unrestricted conditional proof and put a restriction on U.G. , or unrestricted Generalization and put restriction on Deduction Theorem. Can you give examples of the former and the latter.
Also can you recommend a book, since this issue seems rather nuanced.

Comment: @john - you can see the post [Generalization rule and logical consequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580796/elliott-mendelson-introduction-to-mathematical-logic-fourth-edition-gen-rul) as well as [Two forms of Generalization Rule in logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993715/two-forms-of-generalization-rule-in-logic).

Answer (score 1):

I have used a different kind of format for these things, so don't know if this answer will help.  But it seems kind of similar, so will give it a try.

Here is the version I have learnt of the *Deduction Theorem*, which I think is essentially the same as what you are calling *conditional proof*:

> if a formula $\Psi$ can be proved from a set of assumptions $\Sigma\cup\{\Phi\}$, and if the proof never involves applying the generalisation rule to a variable which is free in $\Phi$, then $\Phi\to\Psi$ can be proved from $\Sigma$.

From this point of view, the problem is not actually in line 3 but in line 6: your formula $\Phi$ is $Rx$ and $\Psi$ is $Sx$ and $\Sigma$ contains the formula in line 1.  Since $x$ is free in $\Phi$, it is not correct to say that line 6 is deduced from line 1.

To understand the reasons behind this, it may help to consider some simpler cases.  An easy case of the Deduction Theorem used correctly is:

> from $Rx$ we can prove (in one line!) $Rx$; therefore, $Rx\to Rx$ is a theorem.

This is clearly reasonable, because $Rx\to Rx$ is always true.  On the other hand, here is a simple incorrect use of the Deduction Theorem:

> from $Rx$ we can use generalisation to prove $\forall x\,Rx$; therefore $Rx\to\forall x\,Rx$ is a theorem.

This is clearly **not** reasonable, since $Rx\to\forall x\,Rx$ is not always true and therefore we would not want it as a theorem.  I think perhaps where you are going astray is when you say

> Probably the assertion of "$Rx$" means that this statement function is always true.

On the contrary, we are not asserting that $Rx$ is always true; and maybe even "asserting" is not a good word, we are just temporarily assuming it.  After all, when we proved $Rx\to Rx$ as a theorem, it didn't matter whether $Rx$ is true or not, the theorem just says that **if** it's true, then it's true.  However in the following example we are, in effect, saying that if $Rx$ is hypothetically true even in one case, then it must always be true, which is clearly wrong.

Not sure if all these words help, but see how you go.

Comment: If "$Rx\to\forall x\,Rx$" is invalid, why is it listed as a proof method for non-indented proofs in the first place? In the original proof posted above it is used to go from line $6$ to line $7$. Specifically the universal generalization rule states "from $Fx$ we can infer $ \forall x (Fx )$, where $x$ is an arbitrary selected individual". This seems equivalent to "$Fx\to\forall x\,Fx$" which as you stated is invalid and should not be allowed. So we have a proof method that is based on an invalid inference?

Comment: Also I don't understand this "From this point of view, the problem is not actually in line 3 but in line 6: your formula $\Phi$ is $Rx$ and $\Psi$ is $Sx$ and $\Sigma$ contains the formula in line 1.  Since $x$ is free in $\Phi$, it is not correct to say that line 6 is deduced from line 1." I think this gets to the heart of the matter. Generalization is not the problem per se , but something to do with $x$ being free or not free?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use generalization on x when x occurs free in undischarched assumptions of your proof. This is way of saying that you do not assume any properties of x so x can by any object. For more explanation you can consult logic and structure written by Dirk van Dalen or Mathematical Logic by Chiswell.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is systemic but applies to each system. Generally, in prenex normal form, $M(\varphi) \vdash \forall x M(x)$, i.e., UG, is not allowed unless $M(x)$ does not include $\varphi$, where $\varphi$ an individual instantiation of the quantifier $x$. Informally, we can see that under this condition, what $\varphi$ is does not matter. The important thing is that $\varphi$ not be in $M(x)$. This preserves logical truth but not truth. See. Herbrandization, so soundness (of an inference) does not matter but consistency (of the system) does.

$\vdash M(\varphi)$ if and only if $\vdash \forall x M(x) : \varphi \not \in M(x)$.

This does not mean that $M(\phi) \vdash \forall x M(x)$ is sound even if $\varphi \not \in M(x)$.

Comment: I'm confused by this. Why are you talking about soundness? We are looking at natural deduction proofs , which is a syntactic thing. Can you give an example where it is not sound and what does that to do with universal generalization proof method. And what is the difference between logical truth and truth. I guess the former is true by logical validity and the latter is true in the sense that the premises are true.