# Anita Tabacco include zero to N?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, absolute-value

I have two problems actually, first one:
Proffesor always grumbled that  Anita Tabacco include zero to natural numbers, and proffesor dont include zero to the natural numbers when explain somethink or give any examples, I wasnt at his first lecture, so i dont know the reason of its statement by proffesor

Another one:
Today while we study absolute value there were notion or i dont know how its called:
[image]

and me dear proffesor said that the case when $x>or=0$ is a wrong and $x$ only more than zero, after give some examples by using $sin$ but trigonometry is my achilles' heel and i just couldnt keep up after his thoughts.

If someone have any idea about it please, I in need of help.

Comment: On the "thorny" issue about $0 \in \mathbb N$ or not, see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417042/how-is-mathbb-n-actually-defined),

Comment: Related : Claudio Canuto & Anita Tabacco, [Mathematical Analysis I](https://books.google.it/books?id=wtr5BwAAQBAJ&pg=PR3) (2015).

Comment: Yeah its definly it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the absolute value as
$$ |x| = \begin{cases} x &\text{if }x\ge 0 \\ -x &\text{if }x<0 \end{cases} $$
or
$$ |x| = \begin{cases} x &\text{if }x > 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }x=0 \\ -x &\text{if }x<0 \end{cases} $$
or even
$$ |x| = \begin{cases} x &\text{if }x > 0 \\ -x &\text{if }x\le 0\end{cases} $$

Since they all define exactly the same function (they all make $|0|=0$, just with different words), they are all equally correct.