# What is the error in this deduction of $ \exists x (P) \leftrightarrow P$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

We use [Hilbert-style systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Hilbert-style_systems_and_natural_deduction). Let $\mathrm{Ax}$ be the set of all logic axioms (tautologies and quantifer axioms). Then for any formula $P$ where there's a free variable $x$, we have $\mathrm{Ax} \cup \{P\} \vdash \forall x(P)$ (using [UG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)) and $\mathrm{Ax} \cup \{\forall x(P)\} \vdash P$ (using Specification Axiom, Q1 in [this page](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/02%3A_Deductions/2.03%3A_The_Logical_Axioms)). Then from deduction theorem and [biconditional introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_introduction) we have $\mathrm{Ax} \vdash P \leftrightarrow \forall x(P)$.

Then consider tautology $(Q \leftrightarrow R) \to (\lnot Q \leftrightarrow \lnot R)$, substituting $P$ and $\forall x P$ into $Q$ and $R$ respectively, we get $$\mathrm{Ax} \vdash (P \leftrightarrow \forall xP) \to (\lnot P \leftrightarrow \lnot  \forall x P),$$
and again from deduction theorem, we have $\mathrm{Ax} \vdash (\lnot P \leftrightarrow \lnot \forall x P)$. Next, take any forumula $T$ with a free variable $x$ and let $P = \lnot T$, we have $$\mathrm{Ax} \vdash (\lnot \lnot T \leftrightarrow  \lnot \forall x \lnot T).$$
Since $\lnot \lnot T$ is equivalent to $T$ and $\lnot \forall x (\lnot T)$ is equivalent  to $\exists x (T)$, we have
$$\mathrm{Ax} \vdash (T \leftrightarrow  \exists x T).$$
However, this conclusion is obviously wrong. Where does the error occur in the deduction above?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580796/elliott-mendelson-introduction-to-mathematical-logic-fourth-edition-gen-rul) regarding Gen rule.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh you are right! I just checked my notes and found we need $P$ to be a sentence (no free variable) to use deduction thereom to get $\mathrm{Ax} \vdash P \to Q$ from $\mathrm{Ax}\cup\{P\}\vdash Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA could you write an answer so that I can select it as accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, in Hilbert-style proof systems, there are some restrictions regarding the interaction of Gen rule and Deduction Theorem.

If Gen allows us to prove $Γ,P⊢∀xPx$ without restrictions, we cannot use DT to prove $Γ⊢P→∀xPx$.

See e.g. [Mendelson's textbook](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic/FS-sCQAAQBAJ).

The issue is related to the fact that in the standard semantics for FOL, $P→∀xPx$ is NOT valid.